# Write to MongoDB from JavaScript based website

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say we've got a very simple website of a typical format

```
<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to write to MongoDB from the above JavaScript?

I found tutorials like [this one](http://blog.modulus.io/mongodb-tutorial) but they always refer to *running the file using node* and all examples provided only show how to run it locally.

I'm not expecting an end to end solution but a general guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it's not possible... MongoDB runs on server side, your page/script runs on client side.

What you need is REST web service on server side (say, on Node.js, using express/hapi/other) where you are running Mongo, and then

**(1)** you (asynchronously) send request to server,
**(2)** run the code on the node,
**(3)** the code queries Mongo, and
**(4)** then you return data from server to page.